# Thinkpad Edge E330 refuses to boot from USB after installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, uefi, thinkpad

Before I installed Ubuntu my Thinkpad edge bios allowed me to specify boot devices, their order etc. Now it only says Ubuntu in the boot device list. I am thinking this has to do something with UEFI but I am not sure what to do exactly. I tried every sensible combination of BIOS settings but nothing helps. Maybe someone had a similar issue.

Comment: If you enter the BIOS settings, what options are there for boot devices?

Comment: there is just one boot device and it is called "1. ubuntu", as I said, before there were other devices like network etc.

Comment: Is there anywhere that lets you choose between hard drive, USB, network, CD drive, etc.?

Comment: Well that's the problem - not anymore.

Comment: Does the Fn + F12 menu after spamming Enter button, upon booting, reveal anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly a firmware (what manufacturers and most people call a "BIOS," although it's not) bug. I recommend you go to your manufacturer's site and look for an update.

If that fails, my only suggestion is to use a third-party boot manager that will provide its own way to boot an external medium. My own [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) should do this, although in some cases you'll need to hit the Esc key to re-scan for bootable devices after it's booted.

---

**Edit:** It occurred to me after making the original post that disabling any "fast startup" type options in the firmware might also resolve the problem. Sometimes these options prevent the firmware from detecting a removable USB flash drive, so if such an option was accidentally enabled, it could cause the symptoms you're seeing.

Comment: That's a great utility worked perfectly. Apparently firmware upgrade is not that straightforward on Linux for these laptops as only Windows utilities are available. But this should keep my mind at peace that I can at least boot a linux distro from USB if things go south.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the similar issue where the black screen was shown and hang up there when booting Ubuntu from USB HDD. I found that **ext4** partition type is not supported by thinkpad edge 15. I reinstalled Ubuntu on the USB HDD by reformatting it with **ext2**. I suggest you to cross check the partition type. Before using a third party boot manager.

Answer (score -1):

For everybody having this problem then I finally fixed it by going into BIOS and reset it to default settings. Then I was able to boot up the computer with something else than Ubuntu.